# How to troubleshoot OpenVPN connection fail?

Tags: linux, openvpn

I'm using Fedora 38. I set up OpenVPN on AWS. I downloaded the OpenVPN client cert. When I try to connect it fails.
I'm not sure how to move forward with diagnosing the problem.
Basically, I try (as per the [OpenVPN page](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/connecting-to-access-server-with-linux/)):

```
sudo openvpn3 config-import --config profile-5.ovpn
Configuration imported.  Configuration path: /net/openvpn/v3/configuration/fbe8
sudo openvpn3 session-start --config profile-5.ovpn
** ERROR ** Could not establish a connection with 'net.openvpn.v3.sessions'
```

So I try to get more info with:

```
sudo openvpn3 log --log-level 6 --config profile-5.ovpn
```

But the results haven't been helpful to me:

```
g_mutex_clear() called on uninitialised or locked mutex
Aborted
```

Additional recommendations from [here](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/issues/42) - suggest using:

```
/usr/libexec/openvpn3-linux/openvpn3-service-sessionmgr
```

which doesn't exist.
I tried:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/openvpn3-linux/openvpn3-service-configmgr
```

but that throws an exception. terminate called after throwing an instance of

```
'DBusException'
  what():  openvpn3-service-configmgr could not register 'net.openvpn.v3.configuration' on the D-Bus
Aborted
```

A newer thread [here](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/issues/171) - then recommends manually setting the log level.

```
openvpn3-admin log-service --log-level 6
openvpn3-admin netcfg-service --config-set log-level 6
```

Which I did. I see a glib error - and the thread mentions Glib issues:

```
(process:67252): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:04:07.329: g_object_unref: assertion 'old_ref > 0' failed
```

Not sure where to go from here.
Please advise.

Comment: Revert the logging to level 3 and include the resulting debug log in your question. Higher levels aren't useful until you've applied a gross review. Also include the configuration so we can see what you're working with. Redact if you must, but (a) explain what you've redacted and why, (b) make sure you replace like-for-like _consistently_ and _everywhere_